# Why won't current_user work as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using devise for authentication, `undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass` is raised from the following view code:

```
<% @relationships.each do |relationship| %>
  <div><%= relationship.box.size  %></div>
<% end %>
```

only when I define @relationships in my controller as

```
@relationships = current_user.relationships
```

but not when I define it as

```
@relationships = User.find(current_user.id).relationships
```

Shouldn't those two definitions be identical?

I have the following associations:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :box

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many: :relationships
  has_many: :boxes, through: :relationships

end

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many: :relationships
  has_many: :users, through: :relationships

end
```

I hope I've provided the right information; this is the first time I haven't been able to find an answer on stack overflow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide code of .size method of Box model

Comment: Everything seems fine.. Can you check what `puts current_user.class` prints? Also, try once with: `current_user.becomes(::User).relationships`

Comment: atmaish, it prints User, and current_user.becomes(::User).relationships works. Any idea why current_user.relationships doesn't?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more code, but you might be doing something where you save the current user which, as an after-effect, creates whatever thing it is that `.name` is being called on.  When you call `current_user`, you have the ActiveRecord model that's in memory, which might not have the associated thing from the database that has the `.name`, whereas when you do `User.find(current_user.id)` you're essentially reloading it from the database.  What happens when you do `@relationships = current_user.reload.relationships`?

Comment: Amit, I've edited my question to replace 'name' with 'size'. Hope that clears up some of the confusion. `@relationships = current_user.reload.relationships` works as I would have expected current_user.relationships to. Is there a way to avoid the `reload` call? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had instantiated another object through current_user, `@relationship = current_user.relationships.new`, in the same action. After changing that assignment to `@relationship = Relationship.new`, I was able to remove `.reload` in the call to `current_user` on the next line. Thanks, @AmitKumarGupta, for helping a newbie out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created another object through current_user (current_user.relationships.new) in the same action:

```
@relationship = current_user.relationships.new
@relationships = current_user.reload.relationships #reload required
```

After making the following change to the first assignment, the reload call could be removed:

```
@relationship = Relationship.new
@relationships = current_user.relationships
```

Special thanks to @AmitKumarGupta for helping a newbie out!